# Assign a number of people for an appointment in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm currently doing an appointment scheduling system.

So, I have time slot of 15 minutes for each hour and, for 9:00am, 10:00am, 11:00am, 2:00pm, 3:00pm, 4:00pm, I will only put 1 patient for these time slot. Then for the rest time slot it will be 2 patients.

How do I code this in PHP?

Below is the code I did for the **form**:

```
<form method="POST" action="MAppointment.php">
        Patient Name: <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required> 
        <br>
        Phone Number: <input type="text" name="contact" class="form-control" required>
        <br>
        Appointment Date: <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" onchange="AjaxFunctionForTime" required>
        <br>
        Appointment Time: <select name="time" class="btn1" id="time" required>
        <option value="9:00">9:00am</option>
        <option value="9:15">9:15am</option>
        <option value="9:30">9:30am</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00am</option>
        <option value="10:15">10:15am</option>
        <option value="10:30">10:30am</option>
        <option value="11:00">11:00am</option>
        <option value="11:15">11:15am</option>
        <option value="11:30">11:30am</option>
        <option value="14:00">2:00pm</option>
        <option value="14:15">2:15pm</option>
        <option value="14:30">2:30pm</option>
        <option value="15:00">3:00pm</option>
        <option value="15:15">3:15pm</option>
        <option value="15:30">3:30pm</option>
        <option value="16:00">4:00pm</option>
        <option value="16:15">4:15pm</option>
        <option value="16:30">4:30pm</option>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Book the Appointment">
```

And this is the code in **MAppointment.php**

```
<?php
include('session.php');

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phoneNumber=$_POST['contact'];
$appointmentDate=$_POST['date'];
if(isset($_POST['time'])){
    $appointmentTime=$_POST['time'];

    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into appointment (name,contact,apptdate,appttime) values ('$name','$phoneNumber','$appointmentDate','$appointmentTime')");
    $pid=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
}



?>
    <script>
        window.alert('Appointment booked successfully!');
        window.history.back();
    </script>
<?php
?>
```

Comment: Your form has no end balise or you just forget it? Why do you write "Patient Name" without using `<label></label>` ? What is your database structure?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is the problem limiting the assigned patients for each time slot?

Comment: You posted no question. We can help with exact problems, but StackOverflow is not a consulting nor training website. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: One idea to achieve what you want : 1/ Create a table "slot_by_hour" with `id | day | hour | slot_available`, 2/ Create a table "patient" with what you need, 3/ Create a table "patient_slot" with just `id | id_patient | id_slot_hour`4/ For each day, you will have one "slot_by_hour" and for each add 1 or 2 in "slot_available". 5/ When patient lock a slot : you create a liaison in "patient_slot" 6/ If you have 2 liaison for a slot with 2 slot_available : it's full, else you can add a new one, same with 1 liaison. Hard to explain but hope you get the idea

Comment: But your question is primarily opnion based, every one can have a different idea about how to achieve it and you have no real question / problem to solve, we can't develop the solution for you :)

Comment: Could flag this question for being too broad as well, as Marcin said, we can help solve specific problems, but not do your project for you